# returned error: TypeError: Cannot call method "value" of null

Tags: javascript, typeerror

Sometimes my object alert doesn't have the array active_sig_list. I need to set activeSigCount to 0. But the following line is throwing an error when alert.active_sig_list doesn't exist. Any ideas?

```
var activeSigCount = (typeof alert.value("active_sig_list") === 'undefined' || alert.value("active_sig_list") === null) ? 0 : alert.value("active_sig_list").length;
```

Error

```
Javascript function [automationAlertTimeOut] returned error: TypeError: Cannot call method "value" of null (xxxxx.js#339)
```

Thanks

Comment: The error means that `alert` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. When the object `alert` does not exist or its property `active_sig_list` returns a "falsy" result it will default to `0`.

```
var activeSigCount = alert&&alert.active_sig_list&&alert.active_sig_list.length|| 0
```

This is still not completely "fool-proof": if `alert.active_sig_list` is a string then the length of this string would be returned.

Comment: If `alert` is `null` this will still throw an exception.

Comment: @Pointy, of course, you are right. I corrected my answered, also realizing that `value` was probably not a property of the object `alert`.